# DynamoDB - Delete item - The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-js

I've gone through many answers on stack overflow for similar questions. But the problem is a bit different here. I know that I should be sending the key to delete the operation (pk or pk/sk). But in my case, I only have one key in schema (verified by describe-table)

```
{ .....
"TableName": "**********",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "user_id",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            }
        ],
  ....}
```

The table has been create using following sam code

```
DynamoDbTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: "user_id"
        AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: "user_id"
        KeyType: "HASH"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: True
      TableName: !Ref TableName
```

Here are the params that I'm creating for the delete call

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});
const deleteParams = {
      TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
      Key: {
        user_id: connectionData.Items[0].user_id
      }
    };
 try {
      let response = await docClient.delete(deleteParams).promise();
      console.log('deleted');
    } catch (err) {
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: 'Failed to disconnect: ' + JSON.stringify(err)
      };
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Try converting user_id to string

Comment: @jellycsc that is already a string

Comment: Your api call looks correct, so it must be an issue with the data you're supplying. Try hardcoding the table name and user id. If it works then you know it's an issue with the data you're supplying.